# MySQL's query is stuck and cpu is 100% on live but not on local

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services

I have a problem with certain pages on Django Admin that make MySQL's query stuck (cpu is 100%).

A couple of weeks ago, I had to convert all tables from MyISAM to InnoDB. This operation worked fine.

But on certain pages, the request was frozen. After some investigations, I found out that it was MySQL's query.

I noticed that foreign keys were missing. So I added the missing foreign keys and the query worked. It works on my machine (localhost) but not on live. Every time I load the page on live, I have to restart the MySQL server.

I ran the query via MySQL workbench:

- on local: OK
- on live: stuck

Live env: AWS (EC2 with RDS) with `Django 1.10.5` and `MySQL 5.6.x` 
Local env: `Django 1.10.5` and `MySQL 5.7.x`

I am stuck on finding a solution and I don't know what to do now or to look for.

Please advise.

*** EDIT 31-01-2017 ***

Query being executed:

```
SELECT `clients_campaignday`.*, `clients_campaign`.*,  `clients_client`.*
 FROM `clients_campaignday` 
 INNER JOIN `clients_campaign` ON (`clients_campaignday`.`campaign_id` = `clients_campaign`.`id`) 
 INNER JOIN `clients_client` ON (`clients_campaign`.`client_id` = `clients_client`.`id`) 
ORDER BY `clients_campaignday`.`day` DESC, `clients_campaignday`.`id` DESC LIMIT 50
```

Explain query on **local**:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table               | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                    | key     | key_len | ref                                             | rows  | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clients_campaignday | NULL       | ALL    | clients_campaignday_6cd0afe2,idx_clients_campaignday_campaign_id | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                            | 51839 |   100.00 | Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clients_campaign    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,clients_campaign_4fea5d6a                                | PRIMARY | 4       | tool_2017_01_30.clients_campaignday.campaign_id |     1 |   100.00 | NULL           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clients_client      | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                          | PRIMARY | 4       | tool_2017_01_30.clients_campaign.client_id      |     1 |   100.00 | NULL           |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------+
```

Explain query on **live**:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                              | key                                           | key_len | ref                                     | rows | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clients_campaign    | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY,clients_campaign_4fea5d6a                                          | NULL                                          | NULL    | NULL                                    |  145 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clients_client      | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                    | PRIMARY                                       | 4       | tool_v3_prod.clients_campaign.client_id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clients_campaignday | NULL       | ref    | clients_campaignday_campaign_id_283ca030_uniq,clients_campaignday_6cd0afe2 | clients_campaignday_campaign_id_283ca030_uniq | 4       | tool_v3_prod.clients_campaign.id        |  201 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE on **local**:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients_campaignday` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day` date NOT NULL,
  `cache_power` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nb_articles` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `add_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `clients_campaignday_campaign_id_283ca030_uniq` (`campaign_id`,`day`),
  KEY `clients_campaignday_6cd0afe2` (`campaign_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `clients_campaignday_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`campaign_id`) REFERENCES `clients_campaign` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=80960 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE on **live**:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients_campaignday` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day` date NOT NULL,
  `cache_power` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nb_articles` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `add_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `clients_campaignday_6cd0afe2` (`campaign_id`),
  KEY `idx_clients_campaignday_campaign_id` (`campaign_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `clients_campaignday_campaign_id_6dac75d8_fk_clients_campaign_id` FOREIGN KEY (`campaign_id`) REFERENCES `clients_campaign` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=80960 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

*** EDIT 02-02-2017 ***

I found some leads on my local after investigating the EXPLAIN results.

I applied a SQL query that add foreign keys and **optimize** the database:

```
-- Table : clients_campaign
ALTER TABLE clients_campaign ADD CONSTRAINT clients_campaign_client_id_j3w96j6U FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES clients_client(id);

-- Table : clients_campaignday
ALTER TABLE clients_campaignday ADD CONSTRAINT clients_campaignday_campaign_id_69svf27c FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id) REFERENCES clients_campaign(id);

-- Optimize tables
OPTIMIZE TABLE clients_campaignday, clients_campaign;
```

Now the order of execution is fixed but MySQL is still stuck on 100% and I don't know why.

Please advice.

Comment: Can you post the SQL? or is it numerous queries?

Comment: Furthermore you need to perform an explain extended on your local server, as well as on your production server.  You need to look for any differences between the tables structures on each server.  Is there any difference in the data set between your local mysql and the production mysql?  Indexes or lack thereof could be the reason your perception is that the query doesn't complete.  It could complete but just not in an acceptable amount of time.  An index could fix this.  The constraints would not be the problem in my experience.

Comment: @timothy-g It's an auto-generated query by Django. Basically it links two other tables. I have a table "campaign_day" that has a foreign key to the table "campaign" which also has a foreign key to "client": campaign_day > campaign > client

Comment: Furthermore, did you make any changes to the db config when you went to InnoDB?  With InnoDB you want to allocate as much memory as possible to   the buffer pool, which is vastly different from a myisam based server.  You also want the right number of buffer pools configured in relation to the cpus in your server.

Comment: What we really need is both the query, and you to perform a "SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>" for all the tables involved, and an update to your question with that information.  An EXPLAIN EXTENDED ---query-- for the actual query would also be very helpful.

Comment: I have added the SQL query & explain results in my post

Comment: How long did you wait? What does `show processlist` tell you? Also you might have mixed up either the explain live/local or the create table live/local, because the ..._uniq-index doesn't fit. And I would create a different (or maybe additional) index on  `clients_campaignday(day,campaign_id)`, which should suit your query better than your current index.

Comment: Hi everyone, I updated my post since I found a strange behavior while trying to reproduce every steps in my local machine.